# Transitivity of upper bound constraints in scala type checking

Tags: scala, typechecking, type-level-computation

I'm experimenting with type-level programming in Scala. I think the following code should type check,

```
trait T[X] {
  type t <: X
}

trait A[X, e <: T[T[X]]] extends T[X] {
  final type t  = e # t # t
}
```

but i keep getting the following type error:

```
error: overriding type t in trait T with bounds <: X;
 type t has incompatible type
       trait A[X, e <: T[T[X]]] extends T[X] { final type t  = e # t # t }
                                                          ^
Nothing <: A.this.t?
true
A.this.t <: X?
false
```

I though that the constraint `type t <: X` in trait `T` whould force `e#t <: T[X]` and thus `e#t#t <: X`. Am i wrong?

Comment: I can't write up a complete answer at the moment, but note that `trait A[X, e <: T[T[X]] { type t <: T[X] }] extends T[X] { final type t  = e#t#t }` works and probably provides the usage you're looking for.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you very much. Type refinements are so powerfull, that's amazing. If you have some time, i would be very interested in what's wrong with my version.